# How to set blind input field to validate form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, validation

im trying to set up a blind input field with php that will check and make sure the input field is empty and if it is not empty it will not send the message that it is set up to send but I've run into several problems with placement and wording of this here is my code any input would greatly be appreciated.

```
<?php

// Set email variables
$email_to = 'email@example.com';
$email_subject = 'Website Message';

// Set required fields
$required_fields = array('fullname','email','comment');

$fakes = array('Email1');

// set error messages
$error_messages = array(
    'fullname' => 'Please enter a Name to proceed.',
    'email' => 'Please enter a valid Email Address to continue.',
    'comment' => 'Please enter your Message to continue.'
);

// Set form status
$form_complete = FALSE;

// configure validation array
$validation = array();

// check form submittal
if(!empty($_POST)) {

    // Sanitise POST array
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) $_POST[$key] = remove_email_injection(trim($value));

    foreach($fakes as $fake) 
        if($fake == 'Email1') if(!check_for_content($_POST[$fake])) die;
        else {

    // Loop into required fields and make sure they match our needs
    foreach($required_fields as $field) {       
        // the field has been submitted?
        if(!array_key_exists($field, $_POST)) array_push($validation, $field);

        // check there is information in the field?
        if($_POST[$field] == '') array_push($validation, $field);

        // validate the email address supplied
        if($field == 'email') if(!validate_email_address($_POST[$field])) array_push($validation, $field);
    }

    // basic validation result
    if(count($validation) == 0) {
        // Prepare our content string
        $email_content = 'New Website Comment: ' . "\n\n";

        // simple email content
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
            if($key != 'submit') $email_content .= $key . ': ' . $value . "\n";
        }

        // if validation passed ok then send the email
        mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_content);

        // Update form switch
        $form_complete = TRUE;
    }
}
}
function validate_email_address($email = FALSE) {
    return (preg_match('/^[^@\s]+@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}$/i', $email))? TRUE : FALSE;
}

function remove_email_injection($field = FALSE) {
   return (str_ireplace(array("\r", "\n", "%0a", "%0d", "Content-Type:", "bcc:","to:","cc:"), '', $field));
}

function check_for_content($fake = FALSE) {
    return (preg_match('[A-Z0-9._%+-]', $Email1))? TRUE : FALSE;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>

    <!-- Contact Form Designed by James Brand @ dreamweavertutorial.co.uk -->
    <!-- Covered under creative commons license - http://dreamweavertutorial.co.uk/permissions/contact-form-permissions.htm -->

    <title>Contact Form</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.3.0/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="validation/validation.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var nameError = '<?php echo $error_messages['fullname']; ?>';
        var emailError = '<?php echo $error_messages['email']; ?>';
        var commentError = '<?php echo $error_messages['comment']; ?>';
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
<div id="Contactus">
      <p>Chisel Multimedia</p>
      <p>275 Roswell Street NE <br />
    Marietta GA 30060</p>
    </div>
<br />
<div id="formWrap">
      <div id="form">
    <?php if($form_complete === FALSE): ?>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post" id="comments_form">
        <div id="label1" 865style="display:none">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="label">Email</div>
        <!-- end .label -->
        <div class="input">
              <input type="text" id="Email1" class="detail" name="Emial1"  />
            </div>
        <!-- end .input -->
        <div class="context">e.g. John Smith or Jane Doe</div>
        <!-- end .context--> 
      </div>
          <!-- end .row -->
          </div>


        <div class="row">
        <div class="label">Your Name</div>
        <!-- end .label -->
        <div class="input">
              <input type="text" id="fullname" class="detail" name="fullname" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['fullname'])? $_POST['fullname'] : ''; ?>" />
              <?php if(in_array('fullname', $validation)): ?>
              <span class="error"><?php echo $error_messages['fullname']; ?></span>
              <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        <!-- end .input -->
        <div class="context">e.g. John Smith or Jane Doe</div>
        <!-- end .context--> 
      </div>
          <!-- end .row -->

          <div class="row">
        <div vlass="label">Your Email Address</div>
        <!-- end .lable -->
        <div class="input">
              <input type="text" id="email" class="detail" name="email" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['email'])? $_POST['email'] : ''; ?>" />
              <?php if(in_array('email', $validation)): ?>
              <span class="error"><?php echo $error_messages['email']; ?></span>
              <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        <!-- end .input -->
        <div class="context">abc@bca.com</div>
        <!-- end .context--> 
      </div>
          <!-- end .row -->

          <div class="row">
        <div vlass="label">Your Message</div>
        <!-- end .lable -->
        <div class="input">
              <textarea id="comment" name="comment" class="mess"><?php echo isset($_POST['comment'])? $_POST['comment'] : ''; ?></textarea>
              <?php if(in_array('comment', $validation)): ?>
              <span class="error"><?php echo $error_messages['comment']; ?></span>
              <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        <!-- end .input --> 
      </div>
          <!-- end .row -->

          <div class="submit">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message" />
      </div>
          <!-- end submit -->
        </form>
    <?php else: ?>
    <p style="font-size: 10px; color: #255e67;     width: 65%;">Thank you for your Message!</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
  </div>
      <!-- end form --> 
    </div>
<!-- end formWrap -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By "blind" you mean "hidden"?

Comment: yes sorry i mean hidden

Comment: i know how to make it hidden by setting the display to none the probelm i am running into is when i try and have the validation make sure the input is empty and if it is empty to continue with the validation but if it is not empty to stop the validation and not send the message

Comment: A method you can use is to setup a hidden form field with the name `name="catchspam"` for example. Then in your PHP you would setup a conditional statement to the effect of `if(!empty($_POST['catchspam'])){ // do something-redirect or die(); } else{ mail()...}` which is based on a method I used before. @user3446949

Comment: I noticed you have a typo in `name="Emial1"` probably why it's not working. Change it to `name="Email1"` and it should now work.

Comment: Make it a define / constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to much errors in your code, that prevents you from getting correct results

```
<input type="text" id="Email1" class="detail" name="Emial1"  />
```

Pay attention, that `name="Emial1"`, but in php code you check for `'Email1'`. Correct one of those.
Next piece:

```
        function check_for_content($fake = FALSE) {
            return (preg_match('[A-Z0-9._%+-]', $Email1))? TRUE : FALSE;
        }
```

Using $Email1 variable is just out of place. Regex expression is lack of boundaries. At least it should be

```
        function check_for_content($fake = FALSE) {
            return (preg_match('/[A-Z0-9._%+-]/i', $fake))? TRUE : FALSE;
        }
```

And when you calling this function why **Not** condition?

```
if($fake == 'Email1') if(!check_for_content($_POST[$fake])) die();
```

I think it should be vice versa.

Anyway, personally I'll just use something like this:

```
foreach($fakes as $fake)
    if(!empty($_POST[$fake])) { die();} 
// dont need 'else'
```

Also when debugging your php code, make sure you turn on errors, it realy helps

```
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

Comment: Is there any other suggestions you have to stop spam bits from trying to get in because it works correctly now but the spam bits are still getting through

Comment: You already implemented nice solution and I dont realy know better one. But try to name e-mail field not "email", but just e.g. "field1" - its functionality doesn't depends on field name and  your form will have just one "email".

Comment: okay i appreciate the help just trying to find a solution we are still having 30 or more spam messages coming through in the past two days.

Comment: you can always use captcha or make some more [googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=filter+spam+form). Btw don't forget to accept the answer...